# Is it possible to extract the kernel and device tree from a rom?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rom, kernel

Is it possible to extract the kernel and device tree from an android 6.0 rom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it was that easy then we'd have custom ROMs in no time for every phone on the planet.

What's on our phone are compiled, it's basically impossible to decompile them (modern decompilers are not as powerful as you'd like to think), and sometimes illegal when dealing with proprietary components.

Comment: I tought so with the knowledge I gained while searching the web, but didn't find a clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to build a kernel by creating the soure?

Comment: "Creating", as in writing it all by yourself? Sure, if you can do it and make it work... Or just grab the source released by manufacturers and base upon that.

Comment: That is the problem, The manufacturer never release a kernel

Comment: I figured so... Usually no way out, unless you know how to adapt one from a similar enough device. Think twice before getting your next device is all I can say.

Comment: Do you know if there is a guide to achieve that?

Comment: Nope, I'm not _that_ into development, sorry...